# Simple Dynamic Web Application with Python

Tags: python, event-handling

How would I go about programming a simple web application which 
basically looks like this (actually, it doesn't but I will be able 
to find my way from there once I get the following parts right):

1. User logs in (i.e. I need some kind of authentication).
2. User enters a number.
3. Every X seconds, the server calculates the average of all the 
   numbers that were entered in the previous X seconds.
4. Display the average to the user.
5. The (unique) user whose number was closest to the average gets +1 on 
   his score account.

For server-side scripting I would like to use Python. 
For database access I will use SQLAlchemy.
The server is Apache.
Suppose I have set up the database with the following fields: 
Username, Password (hashed), Score. 
I know how to do (2), (4) and (5). 
For (4) I will probably use XMLHttpRequest though I am not sure whether this 
is the best solution. As my final application will require JavaScript anyway, 
XMLHttpRequest should be fine.

@(1) I think I could find a solution using the "Cookie" module in Python, 
     but I have no idea whether that is the right approach. 
     So what would be an easy but safe approach to session management?

@(3) This is the main thing I am struggling with. 
     I've looked into the "socket" module but I am not sure whether this 
     is suitable for the task. Obviously, I need to have some loop like

1. Listen for X seconds and gather all numbers
2. Calculate average, determine user who was closest
3. Update user account

One thing I don't care about is compliance with old browsers or IE.

Can you recommend some things I should look into or maybe even provide 
some code?

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
first of all you need to hook up Python to apache - for that I would recommend [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/).

Then to the step 1 - you can create your own web forms and query user for the password and set a cookie to them to remember their session (you can store active sessions in the database or use some crypto trick to keep it in the cookie).

Regarding the other functionality, you simply need a nice communication between the python backend and frontend - I would recommend a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) on the frontend, which can parse XML coming from your application or if it really is simple, just output the string and let the webapp fetch it.

Before getting into the final implementation, I would recommend going through an [AJAX tutorial](http://kooneiform.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/python-and-ajax-for-beginners-with-webpy-and-jquery/) which seems to cover the basics pretty well and you can use the built-in server for debugging without bothering with the apache setup.

Alternatively, you can use a framework (for example a very lightweight [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/)), which would save you large amount of time.

Furthermore, regarding the thing you are struggling with - you do not really need a daemon checking as the data can be calculated on each visit - just make sure you store your submissions with a timestamp. Also, you did not say what happens if there are no submissions in the last X seconds timeframe - is the right answer zero?

Lastly, this seems to be quite a "dynamic" app - how are you going to ensure that there are no race conditions? It may be hard to get a reliable results in a high-traffic environment without taking some special precautions.

Comment: Okay, I didn't mention it but I have set up mod_wsgi. For the frontend/framework I have decided on Dojo/Pyramid. Not the easiest way I guess, but hopefully worth the trouble.

Comment: I have worked through http://www.webpython.codepoint.net and am confident 
that I could build _something_ based on cookies but what would be the canonical 
approach? 

Regarding the main part: storing everything in a database and then
working on that could work in this case.
However I will probably also have cases where I need to have a real
event handler. 
The example was a bit artificial but I will check for cases when there
are no submissions.